# Is there any reflex of initial *h₁?

Tags: phonology, proto-indo-european, indo-european, reconstruction

It's commonly posited that all PIE roots consist of two groups of consonants, neither of which can be empty. For example, the root **h₁ed-* has the groups **h₁* and **d*.

However, I'm not aware of any language that shows a reflex of initial **h₁*. All the derivations I can think of would work just as well if the root was ***ed-*, with no initial consonant.

So: is there a language which shows a definite reflex of initial **h₁*, which requires us to reconstruct **h₁ed-* instead of ***ed-*? Or is the initial **h₁* posited just to make the root structure more elegant?

Comment: Fortson (in his famous textbook) very briefly addresses this issue on p. 77 (section 4.7),  saying that e.g. there is no indirect evidence for h1es- (vs. -es) but in exercise 8 (on p. 86) he leaves it up to us to figure this out. He asks us to think about why we have long *a* in Vedic Sanskrit ā́sat- 'monster', which is a compound consisting of the prefix a- 'not, un-' and the pres.part. of the verb 'to be' (from PIE * h1es- in the zero-grade), bearing in mind that the *a* in these forms comes from PIE *n̥. Would you rather think about this exercise and post your thoughts first or?

Comment: cf. Fortson 2010 "Specialists differ on whether to rewrite all traditionally vowel-initial roots  in this way when direct evidence of a laryngeal is lacking; the tendency is to add the laryngeal regardless, for the sake of structural uniformity" (p. 77). Basically, it boils down to "Should we disallow vowel-initial root reconstructions in PIE?

Comment: @AlexB. Ahh, so if we posit *n̥-h₁s- instead of *n̥-∅s-, the long ā can be explained as compensatory lengthening from the laryngeal being lost?

Comment: Well done! This process is called compensatory lengthening or contraction, VHC > V̄C (also in -VH > -V̄), see §3.20 in Fortson 2010

Comment: There are other such cases as well, where Greek shows a prothetic _ε-_ in zero-grade forms, e.g., from the same verb, _ἐσμέν_, _ἐστέ_, _εἰσί_. Had the root been just _*es-_, the expected Greek outcome would have been _*μέν_, _*στέ_, _*εἱσί_ (the final stress in 3pl is analogical in both cases). Also, there are still some roots where it is common not to reconstruct a laryngeal, for various reasons; e.g., _*abōl_ ‘apple’, which is likely a loan word. So not _all_ PIE roots necessarily had a mandatory initial consonant slot.

Comment: FYI, e.g. the very first entry in *Nomina im Indogermanischen Lexicon* is *bʰag- (and you won't find a single vowel-initial PIE root there). The proposed PIE reconstruction for 'apple' is *h₂eb-(e/ō̆)l- (following Beekes), with a note "Der Ansatz ist nicht ganz eindeutig." Other reconstructions are also mentioned and discussed there too on pp. 263-264, including the loan hypothesis and its competing l-stem proposal, i.e. of its IE origin)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "not all PIE roots necessarily had a mandatory initial consonant slot" -- but the "apple" word, if it's a loan, isn't derived from a verb root; the claim that "all PIE roots consist of two groups of consonants" is about verb roots.

Comment: @TKR That’s a limitation I’ve never heard before. It applies to noun roots as much as to verb roots, as far as I’ve ever heard.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I was a bit unclear; I don't mean to imply that there's a fundamental distinction between verb roots and noun roots in PIE (which I don't think there is), but that loanwords, which don't come from any root, aren't necessarily relevant to this constraint.

Comment: @TKR I was a bit imprecise too – I should have said not all PIE _words_. It’s often claimed, particularly by Leidenists, that initial vowels were phonotactically impossible in PIE, which is what I was giving an example against (or at least an example where there seems to be absolutely no reason to reconstruct a laryngeal, other than to fit preconceived notions). Limiting the scope to securely identifiable PIE lexemic roots definitely reduces the possible number of such examples.

Comment: What about Cowgil's law?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some evidence of initial **h₁* in roots like **h₁es-* "be". Alex B in the comments quotes an exercise from Fortson's textbook, Vedic *ā́sat* "monster" from **n̥-h₁s-*. If the root were ***∅es-*, we would expect ***n̥-∅s-* > ***ás-* with a short vowel. But reconstructing it with the laryngeal, **n̥-h₁s-* > *ā́s-* due to compensatory lengthening.

Arnaud Fournet mentions some additional evidence from Tocharian, and Kloekhorst suggests that Anatolian shows an initial ʔ- as a direct reflex of **h₁-*, but this is rejected by most other Anatolianists (like Melchert).

Still, though, there are a lot of roots reconstructed with initial **h₁-* where there's no direct evidence from any of these sources. Regarding these roots, Alex B gives another quote from Fortson:

> Specialists differ on whether to rewrite all traditionally vowel-initial roots in this way when direct evidence of a laryngeal is lacking; the tendency is to add the laryngeal regardless, for the sake of structural uniformity.

In other words, it's elegant to have all roots consist of two groups of consonants, so **h₁-* is used when there's no evidence of any other consonant.

Answer (score 2):

Very frequently, Tocharian has y- where *H1 is expected: for example "horse" is yuk. I suppose Fortson does not mention that kind of phenomenon because Tocharian is far from being completely understood.